# JButton added to a JPanel inside a JTable

Tags: java, swing

I should implement a Kanban Board with Java Swing. I've choosen to use JTable. Every Cell of this table will contain an object we have ourself implemented: a card.

The class Card extends JPanel. We have added JButtons to every card. The problem is I can't reach the buttons.

I've done my best to understand TableModel, TableCellEditor on docs.oracle.com, to understand how to use Tables, but it appears it's more complicated than expected.

This is my code :

```
 class ViewKanbanBoard (extends JPanel) : 

    JTable kanbanBoard = new JTable(new KanbanModel());
    JScrollPane spKanban = new JScrollPane(kanbanBoard);
    kanbanBoard.setDefaultRenderer(Carte.class, new TableComponent());

class Carte (extends JPanel) :
       private JLabel lbTitre;

       public Carte(String texte) {
           this.lbTitre = texte;
           this.setLayout(new GridLayout(1,1);
           JButton btSupprimer = new JButton();
           this.add(btSupprimer);
       }


class KanbanModel() (extends AbstractTableModel) : 

private String titresColonnes [] = {"A FAIRE", "EN COURS", "TERMINE", "EN ATTENTE"}; //chaque colonne est associée à l'état d'une tache

private Carte  [][] = {     
     {new Carte (""), new Carte(""), new Carte (""), new Carte ("")}
};
... (all the methods are implemented)

 public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int col) {
        return true;
 }

 public void setValueAt(JPanel value, int row, int col) {
        this.data[row][col] = value;
        fireTableCellUpdated(row, col);
 }


 class TableComponent (extends DefaultTableCellRenderer) : 

@Override
public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row,
        int col) {
    if (value instanceof JPanel)
        return (JPanel) value;
    return null;
}
```

Comment: When you say you can't _reach_ the buttons, can you expand on that?

Comment: A table doesn't display real components, it only paints a picture of a component. I would suggest you don't use a JTable for a game like this. I don't see why you can't use a JPanel with a simple GridLayout.

Comment: Ok, thank you very much, I understand better now :D Have a nice evening!